# white spaces when using truncate text plugin

Tags: jquery, truncate

Am attempting to apply jtruncate plugin seperately to each of 4 text areas on same page. First text area alignment is justified, rest are right aligned.

Have left comment on the [jtruncate plugin](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/jtruncate-text-truncation-for-jquery.html) blog but heard nothing yet.

My issues are...

A) The justified text bit, on second and subsequent reveals, text doesnt properly justify leaving a massive white space along the top line, bookended by the first two words.

B) On the right aligned text bits, on second and subsequent reveals, the first word of the top line wont jump back up to top line, staying at the front of the bottom line of text. Where it should be, at the beginning of the top line, (top left), there is a white space left.

Hard to explain so...

...I've cobbled together a short [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cress/uTSC9/20/)  which should show what I mean on all 3 counts. Can you assist?

I am VERY new to jQuery and coding in general, often I dont undertand coding terminology or instruction, so please explain things in simple terms for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it! its due to animation starting a new line. Should have scrutinised the text on the plugin blog ~ a salutary lesson.

I managed to work around the problem, by adding a kind of subtitle in my html, which wasn't an H1 H2 etc but simply bold text.

Then I spent hours tooling around with empty P tags, line breaks & white-space: pre-wrap; until I got what I wanted. It took a while, but it works fine now!

Thanks for all the help folks, you inspired me to not give up.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked some more and for the first part (statement text) you can make the following change to the CSS

```
#statement .truncate_more
{
    text-align:justify;
    float: right;
}
```

Which solves the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/QLgqe/

---

Update:

Looked at it some more.  The "change" after the first time is because you are starting with an element that has no display set, setting it to none and then setting it to block.  If you start with it in block you will see no change from one display to the next.  With this you should be able to adjust the rest of your style sheets to work however you want them to work.

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/QLgqe/1/

Comment: Thanks, but I still have issues A) & B).  I did do what you suggested, (I think in ref. to issue C?), moving text onto new html line, but it didnt appear to make any difference. I ended up solving issue C using line breaks.

Comment: It seems that issue A) occurs when using justified text and a different bug is visible if I use left aligned, (see jsfiddle css #statement) so I've switched to right aligned, which makes the truncate work ok, but text alignment when revealed looks goofy and is not so easy to read.

Comment: have done what you suggested, see my jsfiddle, but notice how in the 'biography' section, the first word of the first line wont jump back up to the top - (issue B)   Issues occur on second and subsequent hits of the clicker, but work on the first hit ok. Am at a loss.

Comment: I tried that, (looked at your jsfiddle), but this causes the first part of the text, (which are only called statement text or biography text as example words), to separate off to the left away from the text body. In my jsfiddle, notice how on the top line of both 'statement' and 'biography' text body, the specific words 'statement text' & 'biography text' (Nos of chars before text truncates 'length' in Jtruncate section), are not behaving, ref my issues A) & B) above. Issues occur on second and subsequent hits of the clicker, but work on the first hit ok. Am at a loss.

Comment: @Cress Another update -- now you won't see the after first click change, should help.

Comment: Thanks for fiddling. I had a quick look at your work but alas, the first line starts and remains separated, with the 'clicker' displaying inline. I will have a fiddle & a faff tomorrow, as I've been trying to solve this all day and for now I've had enough. :?

Comment: There is no after first click change (yay) but layout is now showing a diff prob, (Oh nay). When either button is clicked, both headings slide to left. NB I wanted button to  be bot right, so changed css in css section from display:inline-block to display:block, (haven't touched the jq) that went well. However, the afore mentioned prob of both headings sliding is there plus on reveal, the truncate button now appears stuck underneath 'statement biog' text, appearing before 2nd line. Issue with paragraph my html breaks? http://jsfiddle.net/cress/QLgqe/5/